# Rails 3 app deployment, Bundler & Rake issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler

Deploying a Rails3 app, and am having some issues getting rake to find the gems installed by 'bundle install --deployment':

```
$ rake db:migrate
(in /home/jrdev/rails/testapp)
rake aborted!
!!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem ‘mysql2’
```

But, that gem in is the Gemfile, and is also in the vendor/bundle folder…

```
$ bundle show mysql2
/home/jrdev/rails/testapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6
```

My .gemrc file:

```
gemhome: /home/jrdev/.gems
gempath:
- /home/jrdev/.gems
- /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

I thought rails3 apps already had the bundler code to detect which gems to use? I know I'm using the right rake, too (rake db:migrate --trace starts in /home/jrdev/rails/testapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rake). Same result using bundler's exec.

:(

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Wouldn't you freaking know I solve it a minute after asking.

My database.yml file was still calling the 'mysql' adapter instead of 'mysql2'.

Still, what an OBSCURE error message!

Comment: Oh my god.  This is a horrible error message!  Thanks for this.

Comment: Indeed, the error message should be `Unknown database adapter 'mysql'`.

Answer (score 0):

In `/home/jrdev/rails/testapp`, you should find a file called `Gemfile`. Look into it and just add the line

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

somewhere.

Comment: Scan, I mentioned that the line was in my Gemfile, otherwise it wouldn't have been installed by bundler.

Comment: Unrelated question: how'd you code highlight that path in your answer?

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm dumb, sorry. Also, you may enclose any string into ` signs to highlight them in the text (read on the right pane).